# Is there any way to modify the velocity or position elements of the 6DOF (Quaternion) Block in the Simulink Aerospace Blockset?

Tags: matlab, simulink

**The motivation** is that I am trying to simulate a quadcopter in Simulink and visualize the result with ROS and Gazebo, originally the simulation was running in Gazebo and the sensor values were taken from there to Simulink to feed the control loops. Since this resulted in a lot of performance issues, I decided to do the simulation in Simulink with the 6DOF (Quaternion) Block and just visualize the results in Gazebo. Not using Simulink, ROS or Gazebo is not an option.

**The Issue** now is that there is no contact simulation with the "ground" and I would like to avoid trying to simulate that (solutions for contact simulations are still appreciated though). Are there any ways to directly modify the position and velocity components of the 6DOF block?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.